# add new row to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a new row to a dataframe. I know that it is usually done with `dataframe.append()` method but it will not work for my case. Why it does not work is because the user can read any csv file he/she uploads to my app so I have no idea how the dataframe looks like. In psuedo code I did something like this:

1. User uploads a csv file
2. I parse through it and I display it on a website
3. The user clicks on a button to add new row and is redirected to a website where it dynamically generates text fields to type in the information for the new row. The field is generated depending on numbers of columns the dataframe has:

```
for headers in df.columns.values.tolist() 
#generate field with name header
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="{{headers}}" placeholder="{{headers}}"></input>
```

4. The user then types in the values for the new row and clicks "add button"
5. I can then loop through all values the user typed in.
6. I add new row depending with these values.

When I loop through the values I append them in a list so I get all values in a list like that:

```
['PPIQ.SQU900025', 'PPI output index - All industries', '2020.06', '1183', '1184']
```

I did everything but the last thing is to add new row to the dataframe based on the list above. How can I add these values to a new row? I have been searching but can't make it work.. Please help. I am using flask.

Here is a picture of how I display my data and how to add new row:
[image: display data]
[image: add row]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the list into a data frame and use `concat` to join it to the original one.

Suppose the original DataFrame is stored in `df` and that you have the new data stored in `new`.

```
# List of new values
new = ['PPIQ.SQU900025', 'PPI output index - All industries', '2020.06', '1183', '1184']
# New data as pandas.DataFrame
new = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns, data=[new])
# Overwrite original dataframe
df = pd.concat([df, new], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use append if you create a new `DataFrame` from the new data.

```
df = df.append(
    pd.DataFrame(
        index=(df.index.max()+1,),
        columns=df.columns,
        data=(new_data,),
    )
)
```

This does not validate anything so if you pass less columns of data, an exception will be thrown. You have to validate data beforehand.